Jetpack Compose Glance Widget Not Updating
I have a jetpack compose glance widget that shows a text message on startup.
If the user enables accessibility services for the app, the glance widget should change into a button. But that is not working as intended.
Below is my code.
MyAccessibilityService.kt
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MY_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_TAG"
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        // some code
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        Log.i(TAG, "Service connected")

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            Log.i(TAG, "Updating widget")
            MyAppWidget().updateAll(this@MyAccessibilityService)
        }
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service interrupted")
    }

}

MyAppWidget.kt
class MyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {

    override val sizeMode = SizeMode.Exact

    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

        // In this method, load data needed to render the AppWidget.
        // Use `withContext` to switch to another thread for long running
        // operations.
        val manager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager

        val isServicesEnabled = context.isManagerAndServicesEnabled(manager)

        provideContent {
            MyContent(
                isAccessibilityServicesEnabled = isServicesEnabled
            )
        }
    }
}

MyAppWidgetUi.kt
@Composable
internal fun MyContent(
    isAccessibilityServicesEnabled: Boolean = false
) {

    // Get the smallest dimension to ensure square shape
    val width = LocalSize.current.width
    val height = LocalSize.current.height
    val size = minOf(width, height)
    val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()

    if(isAccessibilityServicesEnabled){
        Box(
            modifier = GlanceModifier
                .size(size)
                .background(GlanceTheme.colors.background)
                .cornerRadius(100.dp)
                .clickable {
                    sendAccessibilityEvent()
                },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                provider = ImageProvider(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = "",
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(GlanceTheme.colors.primary),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = GlanceModifier.size(48.dp)
            )
        }
    }else{
        Box(
            modifier = GlanceModifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(GlanceTheme.colors.background)
                .clickable(actionStartActivity<MainActivity>()),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                "Open app to setup"
            )
        }
    }
}

Before I enable accessibility services, if I put the widget on my home screen, it shows the text as intended. When I go and enable accessibility services for my app, the widget doesn't change. I need to remove the widget and add it again to see the button re-appear.
Can someone help me out ?

The issue arises because the GlanceAppWidget framework does not automatically update widgets in response to changes in external conditions like accessibility settings. You need to explicitly trigger a widget update when the accessibility service state changes.
Here’s how you can fix the problem:
Steps to Resolve:
Broadcast a Widget Update: When the accessibility service state changes, you should send a broadcast to trigger the widget update.
Implement a BroadcastReceiver: Create a custom BroadcastReceiver that listens for the update broadcast and invokes the GlanceAppWidget's updateAll() method.
Modify the AccessibilityService: Send the broadcast from the onServiceConnected method of your accessibility service.
Updated Code

----------
BroadcastReceiver for Widget Updates
Create a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle widget updates:
----------
class MyWidgetUpdateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
      override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "com.example.MY_WIDGET_UPDATE") {
             MyAppWidget().updateAll(context)
         }
      }
   }



----------
Declare the receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml:
----------
<receiver android:name=".MyWidgetUpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MY_WIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
 


----------
Trigger the Broadcast in the Accessibility Service
Modify your AccessibilityService to send the broadcast:
----------
override fun onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected()
    Log.i(TAG, "Service connected")

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sending widget update broadcast")
        val intent = Intent("com.example.MY_WIDGET_UPDATE")
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}


----------
Update the GlanceAppWidget Logic
Your existing MyAppWidget logic remains unchanged. The provideGlance method will now get called whenever the broadcast triggers an update.
----------




This didn't work unfortunately. I added a log in the onReceive and it's not getting trigerred.
